@react-pdf-viewer/core with nextJS fail to build
I have integrated pdf reader
@react-pdf-viewer/core

with nextjs 14. If I run
 npm run build

It fails with
> Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/rehype-slug/node_modules/unist-util-visit-parents/lib/index.js
./node_modules/rehype-slug/node_modules/unist-util-visit-parents/index.js
./node_modules/rehype-slug/node_modules/unist-util-visit/lib/index.js
./node_modules/rehype-slug/node_modules/unist-util-visit/index.js
./node_modules/rehype-slug/lib/index.js
./node_modules/rehype-slug/index.js
./src/app/blog/[slug]/page.tsx

./node_modules/remark-images/node_modules/unist-util-visit-parents/lib/index.js
Attempted import error: 'color' is not exported from 'unist-util-visit-parents/do-not-use-color' (imported as 'color').

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/remark-images/node_modules/unist-util-visit-parents/lib/index.js
./node_modules/remark-images/node_modules/unist-util-visit-parents/index.js
./node_modules/remark-images/lib/index.js
./node_modules/remark-images/index.js
./src/app/blog/[slug]/page.tsx


My next.config.js is:

> /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  webpack: true,
  eslint: {
    // Warning: This will disable ESLint checks for the entire project during builds.
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/pirsch-extended.js",
        destination: "https://api.pirsch.io/pirsch-extended.js",
      },
    ];
  },
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.node/,
      use: "raw-loader",
    });
    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;

Basically its working fine on my localhost, the only problem is during the build for production. I have added above my nextjs config and I am using worker as well to load the PDF file.
